# Output a Wordpress custom field in the text editor

Tags: wordpress

I have created a Custom Field in my wordpress page: eg-custom-link

I would like to output the value of this in the Wordpress editor (not in a php template) If I wanted to echo this in a php template I could use:

```
 <?php $key="eg-custom-link"; 
          echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);?>
```

... but in this instance I would like to output the custom field using the wordpress text editor.

Comment: i would recommend a shortcode to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following plugin to echo a custom field:
https://wp-types.com/home/custom-fields-shortcodes/